# Create Table mySql syntax error (working on other versions)

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

When creating a table in MySQL Version 5.7.21 on a Linux server I get the following error message:

> " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `arbeitstageprowocheab date DEFAULT NULL`,
>     `urlaubstageprojahr int(3) DEFAULT '"`

**when creating the following table:**

```
CREATE TABLE arbeitsvertragsdaten (
  personalnummer int(11) NOT NULL,
  mailadresse varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  handynummerxenium varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  status varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  position varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  probezeitende date DEFAULT NULL,
  wochenarbeitszeit int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  wochenarbeitszeitab date DEFAULT NULL,
  teilzeitbefristet tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 teilzeitende date DEFAULT NULL,
  ueberstundenquotient double DEFAULT NULL,
  arbeitstageprowoche int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  arbeitstageprowocheab date DEFAULT NULL,
  urlaubstageprojahr int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  urlaubstageprojahrab date DEFAULT NULL,
  mutterschutzbeginn date DEFAULT NULL,
  mutterschutzende date DEFAULT NULL,
  elternzeitbeginn date DEFAULT NULL,
  elternzeitende date DEFAULT NULL);
```

It did work on my local machine for development on Version 8.0.16 (Community Server)

Any ideas whats wrong with my syntax?

Comment: at the end a ) is missing before ; was it intentional?

Comment: how is it working on other versions?

Comment: @Sameer Its working like expected: Creating the table without any errors

Answer (score 1):

There is syntax issue.

```
CREATE TABLE `arbeitsvertragsdaten` (
  `personalnummer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mailadresse` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `handynummerxenium` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `position` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `probezeitende` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `wochenarbeitszeit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wochenarbeitszeitab` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `teilzeitbefristet` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `teilzeitende` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ueberstundenquotient` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `arbeitstageprowoche` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `arbeitstageprowocheab` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `urlaubstageprojahr` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `urlaubstageprojahrab` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutterschutzbeginn` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mutterschutzende` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `elternzeitbeginn` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `elternzeitende` date DEFAULT NULL
);      ----- here ) is missing.
```

Comment: Sorry in the orginal file the ` around the column names are there and also the last ")" is there, I just cut it out when copying it to stackoverflow. So thats not the problem.

Comment: check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a0480/1 , it is working fine, if there is some issue at your end then kindly create a fiddle and share